# Does Unity's Microphone functionality support stereo input?

Tags: unity

The documentation for the Microphone class in Unity does not indicate whether Unity supports stereo recording. Does Unity support recording stereo audio from a compatible microphone? It looks like several people have asked this on Unity's Q&A website, but no one has ever answered.

*I understand that most microphones are mono and gaming headsets never have stereo microphones, but stereo microphones do exist. It's just not clear whether Unity supports stereo input.*

Comment: Generally speaking, if you've asked a question on product-specific fora (in this case Unity's) and still not gotten a clear response, there's no way you'll get more precise detail here. Sorry to break it to you. P.S. Don't you think Unity's recording API would indicate whether or not Stereo recording is available? I would say if there's no evidence of stereo recording there, don't expect to make use of it as a feature.

Comment: Do the requirements of your game include a stereo microphone? Do you have a stereo microphone to test this with? I'm fairly sure that the AudioClip returned from a `Microphone.Start()` is a stereo audio clip, but I'm not sure if it's just a duplicated channel or if it would actually support a stereo microphone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is of type ["does technology X supports feature Y"](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2383/40264).

Comment: @MichaelHouse I feel like I shouldn't have to justify the question, but this would be for a non-game application made in Unity that requires support for stereo microphone input using an appropriate microphone.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer The quality of answers on Unity's official QA website is atrocious. They don't enforce the same level of quality standards as SE, so a lot of the answers are just guesses, and the answers that aren't guesses are usually bad advice.

Comment: @Kevin, your not justifying anything. MichaelHouse is asking a legitimate question that could help us find a better answer to your question, or alternativley, find a better question for your problem. As is, your asking if a particular game engine supports a particular feature; and these type of questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Gnemlock I don't see how "do the requirements of your game include a stereo microphone?" could help anyone "find a better answer" to my question. All that would lead to is "if you don't need stereo, use the built-in mono support" which is patently obvious. I apologize if the question is off-topic. However, I do want to point out that the first example question in the site tour asks "does XNA provide a built in way to return the top-most sprite on the screen at a coordinate?" which strikes me as a question about whether an engine supports a particular feature.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Why is this question off-topic, but the example question "[...] does XNA provide a built in way to return the top-most sprite on the screen at a coordinate?" in the site tour is not off-topic? They strike me as roughly analogous, asking if an engine supports a feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I've had a chance to hook up a stereo mic and try this out, I've found that `Microphone.Start()` always returns a single-channel AudioClip, even if the selected microphone is capable of stereo (at least on Windows).